# Graphicsitem/ pixmap not displaying in graphics scene

Tags: qt4

```
ui->setupUi(this);
scene = new QGraphicsScene(this);
ui->graphicsView->setScene(scene);
//scene->setSceneRect(-200,-200,300,300);
//ui->graphicsView->setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing);

QPixmap pic (":/Single_linked_list.png");
//pic.load(":/Single_linked_list.png");
QGraphicsPixmapItem *item = new QGraphicsPixmapItem (/*pic*/);
item->setPixmap(pic);
scene->addPixmap(pic);

scene->addItem(item);
scene->
// scene->show();

//painter.drawPixmap(/*scene->sceneRect().bottomLeft().x()+0.1*/0.10,/* scene->sceneRect().bottomLeft().y()-0.1*/0.10, pic);
```

Above is my code for adding a picture to a graphics item. It's showing the graphics scene but not the pixmap/pixmapitem no matter what I do. What's going wrong and how can I fix it?

Also I intend to further animate that image. Which container would be most suitable for this, picmap or pixmap item in a graphics scene?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your scene setup seems fine. You can check if your scene works properly by adding QGraphicsRectItem at any desired position on the scene.

Adding pixmap to your existing scene -

```
QGraphicsPixmapItem *newItem=new QGraphicsPixmapItem(QPixmap(":/Single_linked_list.png"));
scene->addItem(newItem);
```

This will add the pixmap item to the scene as well as show it. You don't need to call it explicitly to show the image.

If you want to apply normal animations like translation, rotation or scaling, you can simply use the setPos, setScale or setTransform functions. For better control, you can use Animation Framework provided by Qt. It applies to any QGraphicsItem i.e. also QGraphicsPixmapItem. Check out the documentation for more reference.

Take a look at this video for Qt GraphicsView basics - http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b35JF4LqtBs and check this link for simple QGraphicsItem animation - http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fmSs2mNGh9I

Answer (score 1):

Check whether the QPixmap object was properly initialized with the given resource. You can do this by calling QPixmap::isNull(). If it's null, it wasn't properly initialized and the problem is the resource.